# Calling a method through CIL DynamicMethod

Tags: c#, cil

I'm trying to call a method through il and although the instructions seems to be correct i'm getting a System.Security.VerificationException: 'Operation could destabilize the runtime.'

the call looks like `var a = Configuration.JsonHandler.Deserialize(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), "{}")`

using ILDASM this generates the following instructions:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Run() cil managed
{
// Code size       27 (0x1b)
.maxstack  8
IL_0000:  call       class IJsonHandler Configuration::get_JsonHandler()
IL_0005:  ldtoken    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,object>
IL_000a:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_000f:  ldstr      "{}"
IL_0014:  callvirt   instance object IJsonHandler::Deserialize(class [mscorlib]System.Type,string)
IL_0019:  pop
IL_001a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Run
```

The c# code for the dynamic method/il

```
        var jHandlerGetter = typeof(Configuration).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(IJsonHandler)).Select(p => p.GetGetMethod()).First();
        var deserializeMethod = Configuration.JsonHandler.GetType().GetMethod("Deserialize");

        var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("DynamicMethod", null, null, true);
        var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, jHandlerGetter);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "{}");

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, deserializeMethod);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var action = (Action)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));

        action();
```

Using an il visualizer i can see that the above generates **exactly** the same instructions.

```
IL_0000: call       IJsonHandler get_JsonHandler()/Configuration
IL_0005: ldtoken    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]/
IL_000a: call       System.Type GetTypeFromHandle(System.RuntimeTypeHandle)/System.Type
IL_000f: ldstr      "{}"
IL_0014: callvirt   System.Object Deserialize(System.Type, System.String)/JHandler
IL_0019: pop        
IL_001a: ret
```

Anyone could point me what am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Operation could destabilize the runtime.` error is caused by the wrong type you are trying to get the MethodInfo. You have to use the interface type rather than the implementation.

Like this:

```
var deserializeMethod = typeof(IJsonHandler).GetMethod("Deserialize");
```

I also assume that you want to return with the result of the `Deserialize()`, so you should say so at the dynamic method declaration:

```
var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("DynamicMethod", typeof(object), null, true);
```

And change the delegate creation accordingly:

```
var func = (Func<object>)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>));
```

In this case you should remove the `Pop` instruction before the `Ret`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! I can't believe that i didn't see that the compiler was using the interface rather than the implementation.